# Codeigniter - Use Pagination without using tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pagination

I found two questions that are not similar to mine so they weren't any help.

What I'm trying to do is use pagination feature without using table because I need to show the data to the user not in a table format. In other words, they will see the name, the date and other stuff in a non-table format.

My controller:

```
 $uid = $this->session->userdata('uid'); //added on sat , feb 28

    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $this->load->library('table');

    $this->table->set_heading('');



    $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/profile/entries';

    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get_where('notes', array('uid' => $uid))->num_rows();
    $this->db->where('uid', $uid);
    $this->db->order_by("time", "desc"); 
    $config['per_page'] = 20;
    $config['num_links'] = 2;

    $config['first_link'] = FALSE;
    $config['last_link'] = FALSE;


    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $data['records'] = $this->db->get('notes', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
    $this->pagination->create_links();


    $this->load->view('profile/includes/header');
    $this->load->view('profile/view_all_notes', $data);
```

My view File

```
<html>
    <body>
<div class="container">

        <h3 class="block-title block-title--simple"> Your <?php echo $site_title ?> Notes </h3>

    foreach ($query->result() as $row) :
     <?php

        foreach ($query->result() as $row) :

            ?>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h1><?php echo $row['message']; ?></h1>
                    <h2><?php echo $row['time']; ?></h2>
                </div>
                <?php

        endforeach;
    ?>  

     <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>



        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

I have tried doing that but it doesn't show it. I just dont want it showing in the table format. Thanks.

Comment: "without using tables" - do you mean without database tables or without HTML tables? If you just mean the latter, then the duplicates you found will be fine - just don't use HTML tables in your template layer.

Comment: I mean without using HTML tables. I'm new to PHP and codeigniter. I don't really understand. Any hlep is appreciated :)

Comment: Ci's pagination will just create links with the page number. The rest of your page is up to you. If you don't want html table then don't use it.

Comment: Can you indicate what is not working with the code you have provided?

Comment: @AdrienXL Yes, that's exactly where I'm confused. How do I display the information in something but not in tables? Like <div>?

Comment: @halfer everything is working fine. I just wan't to know how I can ditch the table and use <div> to show informatin. Thanks.

Comment: Ah right. You need to format your data using CSS then. Out of interest, why are you avoiding tables? That message/time data does look rather suited to tables.

Comment: I want to display like this: http://gyazo.com/44363e5f9195b29c5f1402dec86ae2b2

Not like this: http://gyazo.com/1521391eee0cbe61331da53d65821930

That's like the only reason why.

Comment: OK yes, `<div>` blocks plus CSS are the way to go then (if you are using Bootstrap, then use their predefined CSS according to the manual). Btw, you need to use @halfer to reply to me, otherwise I am unlikely to see a notification from you.

Comment: @hafler can you please help me set up <div> and hook it up with pagination? Thanks.